# React state doesnt upate and list doesnt get rerendered

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, state

in short:

I have a state variable that contains a list of objects

when i click a button a method gets called, that adds an object to the list by using the setState method.

the state doesnt update.
also, the list should then be rendered with the .map function

short code (only essential parts)

```
const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);

...

function addMessage(msg: Message) {
    let newChat = chat;
    // @ts-ignore
    newChat.push(msg);
    setChat(newChat);
  }

...

{chat.map((e: Message) => (
          <Message
            key={e.msg}
            content={e.msg}
            author={e.author}
            self={e.author === self}
          />
        ))}

...

<Messageinput
        sendMessage={(m) => {
          addMessage({ msg: m, author: "You" });
        }}
```

complete code (whole component)

```
interface Message {
  msg: string;
  author: string;
}

export default function Chat({
  messages,
  self,
}: {
  messages: Array<Message>;
  self: string;
}) {
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    setChat(messages);
  }, []);

  function addMessage(msg: Message) {
    let newChat = chat;
    // @ts-ignore
    newChat.push(msg);
    setChat(newChat);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("chat state changed: ", chat);
  }, [chat]);

  return (
    <div
      className="flex flex-col bg-white bg-opacity-10 rounded-3xl p-4 max-w-sm"
      style={{ maxHeight: "720px", height: "100%" }}
    >
      <div className="overflow-y-auto h-full">
        {chat.map((e: Message) => (
          <Message
            key={e.msg}
            content={e.msg}
            author={e.author}
            self={e.author === self}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Messageinput
        sendMessage={(m) => {
          addMessage({ msg: m, author: "You" });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to update the state like this :

```
function addMessage(msg: Message) {
    setChat(prev => [ ...prev , msg]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your `addMessage` function:

```js
let newChat = chat;
newChat.push(msg);
setChat(newChat);
```

You are mutating the existing array, then setting the state variable to the new array. I suggest reading [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) around `useState`, as what you just did is completely wrong.

Either copy `newChat` first or use the mutator function approach:

```js
setChat([...chat, msg]);
// or
setChat(arr => [...arr, msg]);
```

In React, state should almost never be directly mutated, but instead copied with different values. Because you are calling `setChat` with the value it is already set to, React basically goes "oh the state variable already is that value, no need to re-render" and that's why it doesn't update.